# How do I get pandas dataframe after reading csv file as a thread?

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading

I am trying to read CSV files in a thread in pandas. It looks like I am able to run but I don't get the dataframe to append. How do I get the result back so I can append it to another df?

Here is the code I used.

```py
import threading
import pandas as pd
def read_file(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    return df
myfile = 'accelerometer.csv'
threads = []
t1= threading.Thread(target=read_file,args=[myfile])
t2= threading.Thread(target=read_file,args=[myfile])
t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
```

I checked the value of `t1` it gives me `<Thread(Thread-1, stopped 27200)>`  instead of dataframe. I hope someone can help me with this issue.

Thank you

Comment: you can use `df1=t1.result()`, `df2=t2.result()` and the resultant df = `pd.concat([df1, df2])`